# TCPDF ERROR: TCPDF requires the Imagick or GD extension to handle PNG images with alpha channel

Tags: centos, php, nginx, imagemagick

I deployed my app and there's a feature to show the document as pdf, but I got this error message:

> TCPDF ERROR: TCPDF requires the Imagick or GD extension to handle PNG images with alpha channel.

My current php version:

```
PHP 7.2.19 (cli) (built: May 29 2019 11:04:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

My current gd & ImageMagick installed:

```
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.2.5
GD library Version => 2.2.5
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2019-02-01 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Imagick using ImageMagick library version => ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2019-02-01 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright => Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date => 2019-02-01
ImageMagick number of supported formats:  => 209
ImageMagick supported formats => 3FR, A, AAI, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, B, BGR, BGRA, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, C, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DNG, DOT, DPX, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, EXR, FAX, FITS, FRACTAL, FTS, G, G3, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GROUP4, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, ICB, ICO, ICON, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, J2C, J2K, JNG, JP2, JPC, JPEG, JPG, JPX, K, K25, KDC, LABEL, M, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAP, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, O, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PANGO, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG24, PNG32, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, R, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RLA, RLE, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VST, WBMP, WMF, WMV, WMZ, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, Y, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

i finally solved it!!
at first i thought the version of gd that creates error, because i found in the internet, the similar version creates error too, so i wanted to change the version but then i found what i missed. gotta restart the php after installing the extra module

> systemctl restart php-fpm